# Firestore query permission denied

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've got a problem with structuring my security rules for Firestore. Specifically:

`db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo("roles.${me.email}", "admin")` always fails with `PERMISSION_DENIED` error.

What's weird, getting single documents works like a charm. From what I understand this query will not violate any of my security rules. It should always return a subcollection of a `isAnyRole(resource)` function.

My security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
}

match /boards/{board} {

    //Board has owner and 3 possible roles:
    //* admin: can do everything, like an owner, but can be removed
    //* idea_reader: has read only access to the board and its ideas
    //* idea_editor: har write access to ideas and read access to the board itself
    function roles() {
    return ['admin', 'idea_reader', 'idea_editor'];
        }

    function isOwner(rsc) {
    return request.auth.uid == rsc.data.ownerId;
  }

  function getRole(rsc) {
    return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.token.email];
  }

  function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
    // Determine if the user is one of an array of roles
    return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);
  }

  function isAnyRole(rsc) {
    //Determine if user is any role or owner. 
    return isOwner(rsc) || isOneOfRoles(rsc, roles());
  }

  function isValidNewBoard() {
    // Valid if story does not exist and data is set correctly
    return resource == null
                && request.resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid
          && request.resource.data.name != null;
  }

  function isValidBoardUpdate() {
    // Valid if ownerId didn't change and called by owner of admin
    return (isOwner(resource) || isOneOfRoles(resource, ['admin']))
                    && resource.data.ownerId == request.resource.data.ownerId
                    && request.resource.data.name != null;
  }

  // Owner and admin can edit. Owner can delete. 
  allow write: if isValidNewBoard() || isValidBoardUpdate();
  allow delete: if isOwner(resource);

  // Owner and any role can read 
  allow read: if isAnyRole(resource);

  match /ideas/{idea} {
    // Any role can read ideas 
    allow read: if isAnyRole(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/boards/$(board)));

    //Owner, admin and idea_editor can edit ideas
    allow write: if isOwner(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/boards/$(board)))
                                || isOneOfRoles(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/boards/$(board)), ['admin', 'idea_editor']);
  }

}

match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}

}
}
```

Comment: From the documentation:

When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. This mean that: If in this collections you have permission to access some documents but do not have permission to have some others the query will fail. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

Comment: What i can see is that you are trying to query all documents where  you are Administrator and you expect your security rules will filter the ones that are not admin. This is not possible.

Comment: I see your point. Why then `db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo("ownerId", me.id)` works fine? It filters out boards where I am not the owner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the query, not security rules. It's a small tricky thing that is not well documented. So let's have a look at my query:

`db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo("roles.${me.email}", "admin")`

and let's assume email is `n.surname@gmail.com`. Then the query looks like this:

`db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo("roles.n.surname@gmail.com", "admin")`

So the Firestore first tries to access object `roles`, then object `n` inside of the `roles` and so on and so forth. That's why the query was denied - it was not compliant with the defined security rules. If it worked I could have query boards that I shouldn't be able to access.

To fix that issue I had to modify query using `FieldPath`:

`db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo(FieldPath.of("roles", me.email), ROLE_ADMIN)`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the template literals be

```
db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo(`roles.${me.email}`, "admin")
```

instead of

```
db.collection("boards").whereEqualTo("roles.${me.email}", "admin")
```

So, as you are trying to query for documents that are not covered by the security rules (me.email !== "${me.email}"; me.email === `${me.email}`), you will always get a permission denied error.

Comment: I didn't mention it explicitly. It's Android native app written in Kotlin not Javascript. `"roles.${me.email}"` is correct. I double checked it myself before posting here :D